# Display records in current month, using php and a mysql db

Tags: php, mysql

Im trying to display records in the current month from a column thats a timestamp.
This is my code

```
$query = "SELECT
              donationid
              FROM
                  donation
              ORDER BY
                  donationid
              WHERE
                  MONTH(donatedon) = MONTH(CURRENT_DATE())";

$query_run = mysqli_query($conn, $query);

$row = mysqli_num_rows($query_run); 

echo '<h1>'.$row.'</h1>';
```

Comment: And what's your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not checking the year, so you'll return records in the current month in any year, not just the current month.

Testing a function of a column prevents an index from being used to optimize the query. It's better to use a relational comparison if possible. You can simply create a formatted date for the beginning of the current month.

You also have `ORDER BY` in the wrong place, it has to be *after* the `WHERE` clause.

```
SELECT donationid
FROM donation
WHERE donatedon >= DATE_FORMAT(CURRENT_DATE(), '%Y-%m-01')
ORDER BY donationid
```

Comment: Thank you! But if i were to get records for the current year, how would my codes be. Sorry im new to programming

Comment: Use `%Y-01-01` to make the date for the beginning of the year.